# CreateMutex() seems to acquire mutex even when ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS

Tags: c++, winapi, mutex

I am using CreateMutex to create global mutex to prevent running multiple instances of an application. On first run CreateMutex returns handle and GetLastError returns ERROR_SUCCESS, the mutex is created and acquired. On second run CreateMutex also returns some handle, but GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS. In that case I show a message to user and exit the program.

The problem: when that second instance is waiting to be closed, and then I close the first instance, and then I try to run another new instance, it will fail to acquire the mutex. It will also get ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS, but why? The first instance is already closed, so the mutex should be released by system. That means that the second instance is somehow preventing the third to acquire the mutex!

The problem is solved by adding ReleaseMutex and CloseHandle after failed attempt to acquire mutex. But why does it make a difference?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    printf("Starting\n");

    HANDLE returnedHandle = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, TEXT("Global\\my_unique_name"));
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();

    printf("CreateMutex: %i, GetLastError: %i\n", returnedHandle, lastError);

    if (lastError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Mutex already in use! Cannot run.\n");

        //why is this needed?
        //
        //if (returnedHandle != NULL)
        //{
        //  ReleaseMutex(returnedHandle);
        //  CloseHandle(returnedHandle);
        //}
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This is first instance.\n");
        //RunRestOfProgram();
    }

    printf("Press Enter to close.");
    getchar();
}
```

First instance output:

```
CreateMutex: 200, GetLastError: 0
This is first instance.
Press Enter to close.
```

Second instance output:

```
CreateMutex: 204, GetLastError: 183
Mutex already in use! Cannot run.
Press Enter to close.
```

Third instance output, after closing first instance but not closing second instance:

```
CreateMutex: 212, GetLastError: 183
Mutex already in use! Cannot run.
Press Enter to close.
```

Comment: I think this is the correct behavior from the documentation. ***If the mutex is a named mutex and the object existed before this function call, the return value is a handle to the existing object, GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS, bInitialOwner is ignored, and the calling thread is not granted ownership. However, if the caller has limited access rights, the function will fail with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED and the caller should use the OpenMutex function.*** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexa

Comment: Did you even glance at the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation. In second instance I get handle to the existing mutex, but I shouldn't be able to acquire it. So why the third instance cannot acquire it?

Comment: This also applies: ***Use the CloseHandle function to close the handle. The system closes the handle automatically when the process terminates. The mutex object is destroyed when its last handle has been closed.***

Comment: ***So why the third instance cannot acquire it?*** The mutex still exists even though the second process does not own it. The second process has a handle to the mutex. You are trying to create a new mutex with the same name of the existing mutex.

Comment: So after closing the first instance, only its mutex handle is closed, but the mutex still exists because second instance has another handle to it. So the mutex cannot be acquired, because first instance didn't release it explicitly?

Comment: ***So the mutex cannot be acquired*** CreateMutex tries to create a new mutex. The old mutex still exists because of the open handle.

Comment: With the acquired handle in the 2nd or 3rd process I believe you can use a wait function to acquire the mutex: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject

Comment: @mareko your code is not trying to ACQUIRE OWNERSHIP of the mutex, it is only detecting whether the mutex EXISTS. So of course it makes sense that the mutex exists while you still have an open handle to it. Which is exactly what you want when it comes to preventing multiple instances of your app from running. Ownership does not matter in this case. Why would you want a 3rd instance to run while the 2nd instance is still running? BTW, your error handling is wrong.

Comment: I'm acquiring ownership by setting bInitialOwner parameter to TRUE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `CreateMutex` call creates the mutex. When you call `CreateMutex` again and it already exists, the function opens and returns a handle to the mutex. When you close the first process the mutex still exists because the second process has an handle to it.

`ReleaseMutex` is no needed in this case, only the `CloseHandle` call.

When you call `CloseHandle`, there is no more processes holding an handle to the mutex, so the the system destroys it.